# Disable(unclickable) background content in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a two div one is `absolute` position.
here is a code.

```
<input type="button" onclick="showdiv()" value="show" >
<div id="div2" style="display:none"> 
   some content
  <a href="anylink">name</a>
  <input type="button" value="click">
</div>
<div id="div1"> 
   some content
  <a href="anylink">name</a>
  <input type="button" value="click">
</div>
```

Here is jquery code .

```
function showdiv(){
   $('#div1').fadeTo("slow",0.15);
   $('#div2').show();   
}
```

When I click on `show` button it `fadeTo` the `div1` and show the `div2`. but problem is that `div1` link and button also clickable and the link and button of `div2` is not click able.
How can i disable background link.

Comment: if you are using jquery then use event binding to attach click events and remove the inline click handler to keep js ad html code seperate(unobtrusive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#div1').unbind('click').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Can be done if there are any onclick-listeners on the `#div1`directly.
In newer jquery versions you could do

```
$('#div1').off('click').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

But then again I would not recommend such a solution at all but would rather solve this by using a transparent div that lies above the `#div1`.

Example:

```
<div id="div1holder" style="position:relative">
  <div id="div1">
  </div>
  <div id="div1blocker" style="display:none; position:absolute;top:0; left:0; background:transparent;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Make `#div1blocker`behave like `#div1`considering size and call `$('#div1blocker').show()` when you need to block it.

```
function showdiv() {
  var div1 = $('#div1');
  $('#div1blocker').show().width(div1.width()).height(div1.height());
  $('#div2').show();
}
```

Of course, you can still use fading then:

```
function showdiv() {
  var div1 = $('#div1');
  $('#div1blocker').show().width(div1.width()).height(div1.height());
  $('#div2').show();
  div1.fadeTo("slow",0.15);
}
```

Comment: can u define a little more about your answer @androidavid

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#div1 a').bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
   $('#div1 input').prop('disabled', false);
```

Apply css to show it as disabled.
`fadeTo` doesn't cause unbinding events. i have given you general solution.

Comment: @Axeem see my edited answer. it ll mute input and disable click on anchor tag

Comment: this is not working and problem is that `div2` link and button is not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

The `.fadeTo` just changes the opacity of the element and children. There are other measures that need to be taken in order "disable" them.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="showdiv" value="show">
<div id="div1">some content <a href="anylink">name</a>
    <input type="button" value="click">
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">some content <a href="anylink">name</a>
    <input type="button" value="click">
</div>
```

JS:

This will keep the `<div>` and content visible, but "disabled".

```
$("#showdiv").on("click", function () {
    $('#div1').fadeTo("slow", 0.15, function () {
        $('#div1').children().prop('disabled',true);
        $('#div1 a').bind('click', false);
    });
    $('#div2').show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z487dcd8/2/)

Comment: first I do not want to hide and second is if you see that after 0 opacity it is also clickable point the mouse in blank space and see  that.

Comment: Sorry, was so focused on getting the fade and disable right that I overlooked that link. Should work now with the new Fiddle.